# Spark. Change Nan in array in dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to change Nan to 0 in array which stores in column. Array always have the same size. Here the example:

```
Id Array column
1  [1,2,3]
2  [nan,4,nan]
```

should be:

```
Id Array column
1  [1,2,3]
2  [0,4,0]
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `transform` function in SQL `expr`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

......
df = df.withColumn('array_col', F.expr('transform(array_col, x -> if(isnan(x), 0, x))'))
```